# ARIMA dependency on google colab not working

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, pmdarima

I am working on a time series problem and wanted to try ARIMA model for it.

But while working I am stuck at pmdarima not getting installed onto Google Colaboratory.

This command is running forever and neither it is throwing any error nor it is completing its execution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem by running `pip install statsmodels` just before `pip install pmdarima`.

It looks like a versions conflict.